# SVD rank k approximation: why is it sufficient to project the row vectors to approximate the matrix?

Tags: approximation, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, svd

The way I understand it, the rank k approximation of a matrix A is really just a projection of the row vectors of A onto the span of a subspace of the domain given by the singular vectors pertaining to the largest singular values. Those projected row vectors will be the row vectors of the approximation matrix. I've figured out a proof for why projecting the row vectors on the singular vectors pertaining to the largest singular values gives the best approximation for all the row vectors of A, so that is fully clear to me.

**But what I can't understand** is why having a best approximation for the row vectors as the row vectors for the approximation matrix would be optimal to approximate the matrix in the first place. Why exactly the row vectors? Why not have the best possible approximation for the column vectors and let those column vectors be the column vectors of the approximation matrix? Or would that give the same approximation?
Is there some intuition behind this?

This question was perhaps a bit abstract. I hope people understand what I'm getting at. Let me know if I should elaborate.

Any answer is appreciated! Merry christmas :)

Comment: IMO the most intuitive explanation of the truncated SVD is that it is the closest matrix of rank $\leq k$ to the original one, in the operator Euclidean norm.

Comment: Yeah, don't know if I can get anywhere from the angle I'm looking at. So maybe the norm would be the most intuitive explanation, but I don't know.

Comment: I think from your perspective you can say: project the domain onto the "singular subspace" consisting of the first $k$ right singular vectors. This is the subspace of vectors with the biggest ratio $\| Ax \|/\| x \|$, so it is the "most important" subspace of the domain to the behavior of $A$ in a Euclidean sense. Now the connection to your original perspective is that the row space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$, so projecting the row space and projecting the whole domain do the same thing in the end.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. But I still can't find any intuition for why projecting the domain would give a good approximation. What would happen to the codomain? It seems like the codomain is unaccounted for in the approximation, yet it gives the best approximation.

Comment: You've specified a subspace of the domain on which you approximate $A$ exactly, which has already specified what is going to happen to the range of $A$. There is also a duality aspect, because the SVD of $A$ is related in a simple way to the SVD of $A^T$ (whose domain is the codomain of $A$).

Comment: That's true, I didn't think about that! Thanks! Reading about the duality aspect would maybe answer my question about the codomain.